# Use a variable to identify which other variable to use

Tags: variables, powershell, reference

I have three Hash tables populated with available "tasks" for use in different contexts, and I have three identical bits of code, other than each one makes use of a different hashtable. Not ideal, and I would like to convert this to a function, but I am struggling with how to reference the right hashtable.

So, as an example, I have this:

```psh
if ($global:machineTasks.ContainsKey($taskType))...
```

which is repeated the three times, for `$machineTasks`, `$userTasks` and `$relocateTasks`. One way to approach it is to use a `switch` and a temporary hashtable, like so:

```psh
switch ($context) {
        machine {
            $workingTasks = $global:machineTasks
        }
        user {
            $workingTasks = $global:userTasks
        }
        relocate {
            $workingTasks = $global:relocateTasks
        }
    }
if ($workingTasks.ContainsKey($taskType))...
```

and that works OK, but if the hashtables got really large that makes for a lot of redundant data. So, is there a way to set a variable that just contains the name of the hashtable to use, rather than the whole hashtable, and then use that in the `if`?
In my case it probably isn't needed, as the hash tables are actually quite small, fewer than 50 entries, and each entry fewer than 20 characters. But, as a programming exercise I would like to do it "right', and I assume that duplicating data isn't 'right'.

Comment: It's not duplicating those tables. Just creating a reference to them. You could use `Get-Variable` and store only the name but that still calls the value from memory.

Comment: Aha! I had forgotten that arrays and hash tables are always ByRef. That certainly provides a solution here. And I guess, in a situation that is just a variable, a ByVal copy isn't a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something you could simply nest your hashtables into another hashtable:

```
$tasks = @{
  'machine' = @{
    'typeA' = ...
    ...
  }
  'user' = @{
    'typeB' = ...
    ...
  }
  'relocate' = @{
    'typeC' = ...
    ...
  }
}
```

and access them like this:

```
if ($tasks[$context].ContainsKey($taskType)) {
  ...
}
```